# Matplotlib for flight data visualization (trajectory + attitude)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've been working with a simulator that outputs flight information to a csv file. I wrote this script to have a real-time animation of the flight trajectory of the aircraft :

```py
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

def animate(i, ax):
    data = pd.read_csv('flight_data.csv')
    lat = data['latitude']
    lon = data['longitude']
    alt = data['altitude']

    ax.cla()
    ax.plot(lon, lat, alt, label='Aircraft Trajectory')
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')

ax = plt.figure().add_subplot(projection='3d')
ani = FuncAnimation(plt.gcf(), animate, fargs=(ax, ), interval=500)
plt.show()
```

This is the current trajectory plot my code outputs :

[Aircraft trajectory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5hp1.png)

I would like to add orientation (roll, pitch, yaw) information on that animation, by displaying a polygon like a triangle symbolizing the aircraft. This triangle should tilt itself according to the roll, pitch, yaw angles. The triangle should be drawn at the tip of the trajectory line (only the current position/orientation), somewhat like this :

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jESb3.png)

Here's an example of my flight_data.csv file:

| latitude | longitude | altitude | roll | pitch | yaw |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 51.37810000000002 | 2.3273 | 914.4048973925204 | -2.790024747906104e-18 | 7.521456706397831e-37 | 5.391677412211226e-19 |
| 51.378115000429645 | 2.32730000002288 | 914.4048994329572 | -2.4823579495726334e-13 | 2.614133380873825e-07 | 3.128133219710138e-13 |
| 51.378129984759624 | 2.3273000000912765 | 914.4136382493407 | -0.0001078513257623435 | 0.0023320003336775364 | 3.19950439669013e-07 |
| 51.37814497464779 | 2.3273000002370896 | 914.4242037835747 | -0.0002800933382594903 | 0.0068872012379180515 | 6.283174387827548 |
| 51.37815995443158 | 2.3273000004041005 | 914.4397894612849 | -0.0005206867906275333 | 0.013252297988836093 | 6.283144516965605 |
| 51.37817492879696 | 2.327300000573886 | 914.4607853715331 | -0.0008214558561850814 | 0.021009396990557296 | 6.283090848778253 |
| 51.37818989594557 | 2.327300000690093 | 914.4879777717412 | -0.0011794403068647057 | 0.029769922414923978 | 6.283010009266951 |

I don't know if matplotlib can do such things.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi Dobid. The requiremnts you are saying is not clear to me. It would be helpful if you add current output visualization and expected visualization along with some sample data in your csv's would be helpful

Comment: @Bhargav Hello ! Thanks for specifying what wasn't clear, I edited the post to include more info about what I'm trying to do